# Android MotionEvent equivalent to Java MouseEvent?

Tags: java, android, events, mouseevent

I'm wondering if `MotionEvent` in Android is equivalent to `MouseEvent` in Java?

All I'm attempting to do is get the `x` and `y` coordinates and check if they are inside my View. (I noticed that `MotionEvent` has getters for both x and y)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> All I'm attempting to do is get the x and y coordinates and check if they are inside my View.

`MotionEvent` is the correct way to go for this purpose.

> I'm wondering if `MotionEvent` in Android is equivalent to `MouseEvent` in Java?

They're almost identical, although `MotionEvent` is for touch, but I think you've already figured that out.

Comment: Yeah, what I'm trying to do is find out the x and y coorinates when the user touches the screen. Would the `getX()` and `getY()` be the best methods for this?

Comment: Sorry to bother you about this topic again, but does one need to add a listener to the view, if so, how? :)

Comment: @StartingGroovy: If you are overriding the `onTouch()` method you have to by using `yourView.setOnTouchListener(yourTouchListener)`. Otherwise, if you are just using the default `onTouchEvent()` from your activity, you don't have to.